# Can't deploy Silverlight app to WP 8.1 from VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I'm using MS VS 2015 on my desktop PC and VS 2013 on my notebook. The app I'm currently developing was initially developed for WP8, now I've changed the project to target WP 8.1, but it's still named Silverlight project. The problem is next: when I try to deploy app from VS 2015 the app builds and studio starts to say that it is deploying it, but nothing happens(I tried waiting different amount of time), Studio freezes a little, but when I disconnect the phone it says that it can't find any WP device. On the notebook the same app is deployed within some seconds and runs without any problems. I'm using Lumia 920 to test this. Is there any way to make it work in VS 2015?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 doesn't support Silverlight projects. I have Silverlight Windows Phone apps and i use for this VS 2013.

Comment: Strange, but I can open this project and edit it without any problems. But thanks for the hint!

Comment: I've just checked: I can debug Silverlight app with Visual Studio 2015 using  Device Emulator with WP 8.1, but I still can't deploy this app to device. Are you sure VS 2015 doesn't support Silverlight at all?

Comment: You can't create Silverlight app with VS 2015 , I can't update my old apps with this .

Comment: Sure you can create WP8.1 Silverlight Apps with VS 2015. But I also have problems with some (not all!) apps when I want to deploy them.